# Trigger does not recognize table (Trigger to break up content of NEW.values into multiple rows to insert into another table)

Tags: php, mysql, triggers, mysql-workbench

> **Error Code: 1109. Unknown table 'numbers' in field list**

Why my code thinks that there is no table numbers and **how to fix it?**

And if possible answer question *why use case with triggers?*

P.S Numbers table I have been using combining with sunstring_index so from tables where in some column fields have two words i could split them into two **rows**

Maybe there is sufficient way?

```
drop schema exp;
create database exp;
use exp;
create table IDVU (
`ID` int(8)  unsigned not null auto_increment ,
`VU` varchar(45) not null,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `ix_VU` (`VU`)
)ENGINE = InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

create table sep (
ID1 int(8) unsigned NOT NULL primary key auto_increment,
ID2 int(8) unsigned not null,
V varchar(45) not null,
U varchar(45) not null,
KEY `ix_ID2` (`ID2`),
CONSTRAINT `ID_IDVU_SEP` FOREIGN KEY (`ID2`) REFERENCES `IDVU` (`ID`)
ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
)ENGINE = InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

create table numbers select 1 n union all select 2;
delimiter $$
CREATE TRIGGER `edit` AFTER INSERT 
ON `idvu` 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 

    IF new.VU like '% %' THEN 
        SET @V = SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(new.Vu, ' ', numbers.n), ' ', -1),
            @U = SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(new.Vu, ' ', numbers.n), ' ', -1);
    else
        SET @V = 'NEW',@U = 'NEW';
    END IF;

    INSERT INTO sep (ID2,V, U) VALUES (new.ID,@V, @U);

END$$

delimiter ;

select * from idvu order by ID;
select * from sep order by ID1;
insert into iDVU value (2,'Dd Rr');
```

**UPDATE:** OP wants to create a trigger `AFTER INSERT` to break up content of NEW.values inserted into `table1` into different rows and insert them into `table2`.

```
Table1
Number  Player    Team              Position
  1     Jan Ho    Team 1            C
  2     Mike Dog  Team 3            LW
4 8     Slim Dre  Team 4, Team 1    G D
  6     Mad Dog   Team 2            D
```

break it up into rows and insert into `table2` like below

```
Table2
Number  Player    Team              Position
  1     Jan Ho    Team 1            C
  2     Mike Dog  Team 3            LW
  4     Slim Dre  Team 4            G
  8     Slim Dre  Team 1            D
  6     Mad Dog   Team 2            D
```

Comment: what are you trying to do with numbers table? you have to select from it. you can't just reference a column name without selecting from it

Comment: So the whole principle is to [1] (http://imgur.com/DUDjhET) if table IDVU would be updated with info from table 1 as seen link, than triggers works and inserts the values from table1(IDVU) to table2(sep) as shown in link!

Comment: see my answer for what you're trying to do. no need for `numbers` table because currently you're hardcoding values for the table anyways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you're just trying to break out the strings, you can just hardcode the 1 and 2 in there like this and there's no need to grab 1 and 2 in numbers table since that table is currently hardcoded to contain 1 and 2 anyways.

```
SET @V = SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(new.Vu, ' ', 1), ' ', -1),
    @U = SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(new.Vu, ' ', 2), ' ', -1);
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0d23d/2)

but then i noticed you don't even need to call SUBSTRING_INDEX() twice..this works too

```
    SET @V = SUBSTRING_INDEX(new.Vu, ' ', 1),
        @U = SUBSTRING_INDEX(new.Vu,' ', -1);
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/498b6/1)

**UPDATE** after seeing your comment, I see why you wanted to create table `numbers` so your trigger would be something like this.
First you create table `numbers` that contains rows that has n values from 1 to 10 (possible maximum number of fields to break up into rows).
Then you select from `numbers` where n values are <= number of fields in your number.  Then apply SUBSTRING_INDEX() functions to get the field at n position.

```
create table numbers 
select 1 as n 
union select 2 
union select 3
union select 4
union select 5
union select 6
union select 7
union select 8
union select 9
union select 10;

CREATE TRIGGER `edit2` AFTER INSERT 
ON `table1` 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 

    INSERT INTO table2 (number,player,team,position)
    SELECT 
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(NEW.number,' ',n),' ',-1) as number,
    NEW.player as player,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(NEW.team,', ',n),', ',-1) as team,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(NEW.position,' ',n),' ',-1) as position
    FROM
    numbers n
    WHERE LENGTH(NEW.number)
             - LENGTH(REPLACE(NEW.number,' ',''))
             + 1 >= n.n;

END
```

[sqlfiddle to see trigger in action](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3d9b07/1)

Comment: Thanks, but this is not really what i need! The problem is i want those braked out strings in separate rows but with same IDVU.ID! Any ideas?

Comment: [1] (http://i.stack.imgur.com/KOdDs.png) This maybe will better explain what I want.  Iwant to create trigger edit2!

Comment: i updated my answer at bottom, please try it out and let me know... i created `numbers` table to have 10 to allow up to possibily breaking into 10 rows...if you only breaking into 2 rows it still works ... or 3 or 4 up to 10. it's kinda dynamic up to 10 because it counts number of spaces in `number` field + 1 as the field_count

Comment: I understand that you already have the edit trigger to break out first name and last name? so you should be good to go with this create `edit2` trigger

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was stuck on IF using, but right the moment i saw your code that used SELECT I understood my mistake!