# Automatic trigger that copies data to another table formatted MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, triggers, mysql-workbench

So i have a problem. I do not know how to write a trigger that not only sends datafrom (**Table1**) to another table(**Table2**), but edits it as well as seen in image link - Full transformation at end of the question

```
use ptype;
create table IDVU (
`ID` int(8)  unsigned not null auto_increment ,
`VU` varchar(45) not null,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `ix_VU` (`VU`)
)ENGINE = InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

create table sep (
ID1 int(8) unsigned NOT NULL primary key auto_increment,
ID2 int(8) unsigned not null,
V varchar(45) not null,
U varchar(45) not null,
KEY `ix_ID2` (`ID2`),
CONSTRAINT `ID_IDVU_SEP` FOREIGN KEY (`ID2`) REFERENCES `IDVU` (`ID`) ON
DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
)ENGINE = InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

delimiter $$
CREATE TRIGGER `edit` AFTER INSERT 
ON `idvu` 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

    IF new.VU like '% %' THEN
        SET @V = SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(new.Vu, ' ', 1), ' ', -1) ,
            @U = SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(new.Vu, ' ', 2), ' ', -1);
    else
        SET @V = 'NEW',@U = 'NEW';
    END IF;

    INSERT INTO sep (ID2,V, U) VALUES (new.ID,@V, @U);

END$$

delimiter ;

LOAD  DATA LOCAL INFILE '/Users/MarcisL/Desktop/MySQL faili/CSV/PTCSV.csv' ignore 
INTO TABLE IDVU FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

This is a code that I want to use as base ,because trigger worked very similary in my opinion to what i want now. Code work like this - **if table2(IDVU) was updated than table3(sep) was updated and Player(VU) column from table2(IDVU) was split into Name(V),Surname(U)** -Full transformation at end of the question

In the end my whole script should work like this - [Full transformation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOdDs.png)

Comment: Please someone help! I have tried to make this trigger for long time .........long time!

Comment: What is the issue? Is it an error? Or is the trigger not working as expected?

Comment: I do not know how to write **if part** in trigger  so if there is column like Number in Table1 with 2 values (4 and 8) in one field. How  can I separate this values in two rows like in table 2?

Answer (score 0):

Another my question on this site turned into answer for this question!

[Trigger does not recognize table (Trigger to break up content of NEW.values into multiple rows to insert into another table)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36805897/trigger-does-not-recognize-table-trigger-to-break-up-content-of-new-values-into)